# Regex matching multiple patterns with prefix and suffix

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like so

> This is a (Lock)item response(Unlock) and (Lock)request(Unlock)

I need to get all the strings between the prefix (Lock) and suffix (Unlock)

I need to get

1. item response
2. request

I am working in c# and have tried the following

1. (?:(Lock))(.*)(?:(Unlock))
2. (?<=(Lock))(.*)(?=(Unlock))

Not sure what to put in the middle part in place of (.*)

Comment: You need to make it non-greedy `.*?`

Comment: can u check my answer and see if it meets your requirements ?

Comment: @zackraiyan: Thank you for you answer Sir but I was looking for something more generic instead of what would work for this exact string

Comment: But why wouldn't my solution work if you have `(lock)` ,`(unlock)` in ur string ??

Comment: In .NET regex, (?>([^(]*)) seems good in the place of (.*). Then full regex would be  (?<=\\(Lock\\))(?>([^(]*))(?=\\(Unlock\\))    http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3C%3d\%28Lock\%29%29%28%3f%3E%28[^%28]*%29%29%28%3f%3d\%28Unlock\%29%29&i=This+is+a+%28Lock%29item+response%28Unlock%29+and+%28Lock%29request%28Unlock%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular expression: `(?:\(Lock\))(.*?)(?:\(Unlock\))`

Example code in C#:

```
var r = new Regex(@"(?:\(Lock\))(.*?)(?:\(Unlock\))");
MatchCollection mc = r.Matches("This is a (Lock)item response(Unlock) and (Lock)request(Unlock)");

for(int i = 0; i < mc.Count; i++)
{
    // Groups[0] always contains the whole match
    // Groups[1] contains the capturing match
    Console.WriteLine(mc[i].Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Result:

[image]